# How do I distinguish between button clicks in a form?

Tags: php, html, forms

So I'm creating a database for my website and I want to create an admin section that allows you to add or delete from the table. Here is a snapshot of what I want to achieve...

[image]

In my php file I have `if($_POST['delete_category'])` which correctly gets the delete button clicks, but then I'm not sure how to distinguish which delete button was actually clicked. I'm sure this is a very simple solution, but I'm stuck. Thanks!

Comment: It's easier if you make them links with the id appended to the URL in the querystring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can discern which button is submitted by this following markup (based on your example fetched results from DB):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['delete_category'])) {
    $id = $_POST['delete_category']; // the value="1" or value="3" goes in here
    echo $id;
}


?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Senior Pictures</td>
            <td><button typpe="submit" name="delete_category" value="1">Delete</button></td>
            <!-- each delete button has the same name, but different values -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Engagements</td>
            <td><button typpe="submit" name="delete_category" value="3">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

If I had to guess this makes sense on the fetching: (Note: **Just a sample!**)

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <?php while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()): ?> <!-- assuming mysqli() -->
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?> <!-- assuming on mysql (bleh) -->
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <button typpe="submit" name="delete_category" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table>
</form>
```